# Why does uploaded image permissions depends on it's size?

Tags: python, django, nginx, centos, gunicorn

Web application build using Django Framework

- Server: `CentOS Linux release 7.1.1503 (Core)`
- Nginx: `nginx version: nginx/1.6.3`
- Gunicorn: `gunicorn==19.3.0`
- Django: `Django==1.8.4`

When uploading image which is less than `2.7M` everything works fine.

1. Image is created on server where it should be (`MEDIA_ROOT`)
2. user group and read permissions: `-rw-r--r-- 1 tb360 tb360`
3. Image is served by the web server without issue

But when image size exceeds `2.7M`

1. Image is created on server where it should be (`MEDIA_ROOT`)
2. Image is without read permission: `-rw------- 1 tb360 tb360`
3. Image is not served by the web server
   reason: no read permission on file

After I just add read permission to such image, it is served by web server without issue.

When Testing on local development machine there is no similar problem.

[nginx configuration](http://pastebin.com/wwLZ5V0i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Django is using 2 upload handlers: `MemoryFileUploadHandler` and `TemporaryFileUploadHandler`. First one will keep uploaded file in ram, before deciding what to do with it. Second one will put file in temp directory and move it later to proper location.

Problem probably occurs because memory handler will take only files up to certain size and your system is having different default file permissions for temp directory. That permissions will be kept when moving file from temp to your `MEDIA_ROOT`.

You can fix that issue by setting [`FILE_UPLOAD_PERMISSIONS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#file-upload-permissions) (so files will always have proper permissions) or [`FILE_UPLOAD_TEMP_DIR`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#file-upload-temp-dir) (to store temp files on different location, which doesn't set more restrictive file permissions).

Comment: Thanks for clear explanation! I increased [FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#std:setting-FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE) value in my case.

Comment: Thank a bunch. I already got so far to notice that the different permissions were dependent on file size but your investigations saved me lots of time.